# GWT+ Maven and Eclipse compilation for more than one module

Tags: eclipse, maven, gwt, gwt-maven-plugin

I'm using the recommended [GWT Maven Plugin](https://tbroyer.github.io/gwt-maven-plugin/)  and the [GWT Eclipse Plugin](http://gwt-plugins.github.io/documentation/gwt-eclipse-plugin/maven/Maven.html#). Actually I'm using the maven plugin with the `appengine-mave-plugin` to try to emulate the old Google Eclipse Plugin Super Dev Mode. Following the [Google App Engine](http://gwt-plugins.github.io/documentation/gwt-eclipse-plugin/servers/AppEngine.html) instructions from the GWT Plugin documentation and the suggested sample project [gwt-basic-rpc-appengine](https://github.com/branflake2267/Archetypes/tree/master/archetypes/gwt-basic-rpc-appengine)  I created this project structured that my project runs in super dev mode when I launch the App Engine local server from Eclipse (using the Eclipse Google Cloud Tools local App Engine server launcher tool). From Maven, this process works following: `mvn clean package appengine:devserver_start` and `mvn gwt:codeserver`.

However, the Maven GWT plugin only compiles one of the four modules. This is my `pom.xml`  configuration:

```
<!-- GWT Maven Plugin-->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>net.ltgt.gwt.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-rc-8</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
             <!--  <goal>test</goal>-->
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <moduleName>com.company.Administracion</moduleName>
          <moduleName>com.company.Cronometro</moduleName>
          <moduleName>com.company.Extension</moduleName>
          <moduleName>com.company.Company</moduleName>
        <!--   <moduleShortName>Nubbius</moduleShortName> -->
          <failOnError>true</failOnError>
          <!-- GWT compiler 2.8 requires 1.8, hence define sourceLevel here if you use
               a different source language for java compilation -->
          <sourceLevel>1.8</sourceLevel>
          <!-- Compiler configuration -->
          <localWorkers>4</localWorkers>
          <draftCompile>true</draftCompile>
          <compilerArgs>
            <!-- Ask GWT to create the Story of Your Compile (SOYC) (gwt:compile) -->
            <arg>-compileReport</arg>
            <arg>-XcompilerMetrics</arg>
          </compilerArgs>
          <!-- DevMode configuration -->
          <!-- <warDir>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}</warDir>
-->
          <launcherDir>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}</launcherDir>
          <classpathScope>compile+runtime</classpathScope>
          <codeServerPort>auto</codeServerPort>
          <!-- URL(s) that should be opened by DevMode (gwt:devmode). -->
          <startupUrls>
            <startupUrl>Company.jsp</startupUrl>
          </startupUrls>
          <jvmArgs>
            <arg>-Xms1024M</arg>
            <arg>-Xmx2014M</arg>
            <!-- <arg>-javaagent:/home/.m2/repository/.../appengine-java-sdk-1.9.59/lib/agent/appengine-agent.jar </arg>-->             <arg>-javaagent:/home/desarrollo26/Descargas/appengine-java-sdk-1.9.59/lib/agent/appengine-agent.jar </arg>
          </jvmArgs>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

The `src` folder contains the structure:

```
src/
├── main
│   ├── appengine
│   ├── java
│   │   └── com
│   │       └── company
│   │           ├── client
│   │           ├── server
│   │           └── shared
|   |           
│   ├── resources
│   │   └── META-INF
│   └── webapp
       └── WEB-INF
│           ├── classes
│           │   ├── com
│           │   │   └── company
            │   │       └── shared
│           │   ├── main
│           │   │   ├── java
│           │   │   └── resources
│           │   └── META-INF
│           └── lib
│               └── lib
├── META-INF
└── test
    └── java
```

(All `modules.gwt.xml` files are at the same level of `client/` `server/` and `shared/` folders.(

From Eclipse, I can create a launcher to compile my project with all the params that I have specified in my POM file but I can't automatically execute the war explode and copy process (this is the main reason for build the project from Maven).

Can I solve that compilation process with my project structure? 
Con I use the GWT Eclipse project and Maven together?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use one execution per module to compile.

That being said, you really should split your project into (at least) 5 Maven submodules (one for the server-side code, and on per GWT module, and possibly additional ones for shared code; and you could use the gwt-app and gwt-lib packagings for the GWT modules to simplify your POM files)